# mpdf() library does not work when the function is called

Tags: php, html, mpdf

**Here is my code**

```
$button = '<form method="post"> <input type="submit" name="button1"class="button" value="generate_pdf" /></form>';

$html = '<table><tr><td></td><tr></table>';

echo $html;

if (isset($_POST['button1'])) {
    send($html);
}

echo $button;

function send($html) {
    require 'company/mpdf60/mpdf.php';
    $mpdf = new mPDF('utf-8', 'A4', 2);
    $mpdf->WriteHTML($html);
    $mpdf->SetDisplayMode('fullpage');
    $mpdf->Output();
}
```

I am getting a warning when I am running the function

> Warning: Illegal string offset 'ID' in
> D:\Project\myproject\web\company\mpdf60\classes\cssmgr.php on line 1136
> Warning: Cannot assign an empty string to a string offset in D:\Project\Web\myproject\web\company\mpdf60\classes\cssmgr.php on line 1136
> Warning: Illegal string offset 'LANG' in D:\Project\Web\myproject\web\company\mpdf60\classes\cssmgr.php on line 1139
> Warning: Cannot assign an empty string to a string offset in  D:\Project\Web\myproject\web\company\mpdf60\classes\cssmgr.php on line 1139
> Warning: Illegal string offset 'ID' in D:\Project\Web\myproject\web\company\mpdf60\classes\cssmgr.php on line 1190
> Warning: Illegal string offset 'LANG' in D:\Project\Web\myproject\web\company\mpdf60\classes\cssmgr.php on line 1190
> Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at
> D:\Project\Web\myproject\web\skymediaContract.php:1002) in
> D:\Project\Web\myproject\web\company\mpdf60\mpdf.php on line 8297
> Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at
> D:\Project\Web\myproject\web\skymediaContract.php:1002) in
> D:\Project\Web\myproject\web\company\mpdf60\mpdf.php on line 1706
> mPDF error: Some data has already been output to browser, can't send PDF file

If remove `echo $html;` it will work. But I need to show `HTML`.
I need your help, guys. Thank you

Comment: why do you need echo ?

Comment: People need to see mandatory. @MaxiGui

Comment: did you try to use `print` or `echo ($html);` ?

Comment: Btw, `<form method="post"` is not closed in `$button`

Comment: All syntax is right. I used `print`. got same warning. @MaxiGui

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you send the headers twice: at first with your echo, the second with $mpdf->Output(), therefore the errors. You can open the pdf in a new window or in a frame for example.